# How to parse JSON-RPC table with different type

Tags: go, json-rpc

I want get informations in JSON-RPC file with this structure :

```
{
    "id": "foo1",
    "error": null,
    "result": [
        {
            "key": [
                "hello 1",
                1,
                "world 1"
            ],
            "val": {
                "type": "static"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "hello 2",
                1,
                "world 2"
            ],
            "val": {
                "type": "static"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my parsing function, Key is string table (can't accept int type) :

```
type JsonRpcRsp struct {
    Id     string          `json:"id"`
    Error  *string         `json:"error"`
    Result json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
}

type JsonRpcEntry_Val struct {
    Type     string          `json:"type"`
}
type JsonRpcEntry struct {
    Key     [3]string          `json:"key"`
    Val     JsonRpcEntry_Val  `json:"val"`
}

jsonResult := JsonRpcRsp{}
json.Unmarshal(data, &jsonResult)
entries := []JsonRpcEntry{}
for _, val := range jsonResult {
    json.Unmarshal(val.Result, &entries)
}
```

How to parse "key" table ?... problem is there are different types

key table structure is :

```
[ <string>, <int>, <string>]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding. What is of different types?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Please include your code, and explain how it's failing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unmarshal arrays of different types in Go you'll need to use interfaces and consequently type assertions if you need access to the types.

This will work for you:

```golang
type Result struct {
    Key [3]interface{} `json:"key"`
    Val struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
    } `json:"val"`
}

msg := JsonRpcRsp{}
json.Unmarshal(data, &msg)

var result []Result
json.Unmarshal(msg.Result, &result)

for _, v := range result {
    key1 := v.Key[0].(string)
    key2 := v.Key[1].(float64)
    key3 := v.Key[2].(string)

    fmt.Println(key1, key2, key3)
}
```

After asserting the three interfaces to their types, you can then work with them further, depending on your use case.